# Scrollview's direct Host adding

Tags: java, android

When there is error of "scroll view can host only one direct child", I add one host Linear layout so all the child LL are become disappear so how can I add scroll view and It's direct host so my Data does not being disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take ScrollView->LinearLayout->other view. should be your hierarchy. here make sure that Scrollview and LinearLayout's height and width are fill_parent/match_parent. i guess that is the only reason which makes your other layour disappear.